# Postgresql: delete all comments from database

Tags: postgresql

I have a database for which the comments on objects ([PSQL command COMMENT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html)) are just pollution for us: they are obsolete and in a language that no one reads in our organisation. Hence, I'd like to delete all these comments at once. There are hundreds of them and I don't want to write hundreds of command lines "COMMENT ON xxx IS NULL".

Anybody knows how to do this ?

Comment: You have not accepted an answer to any of your questions, yet. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 and be more cooperative.

Answer (score 2):

Erwin Brandstetter gave a very good answer on how to do this on this question [Removing COMMENT ON from all objects in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237737/removing-comment-on-from-all-objects-in-postgresql) on Stack Overflow.

It basically consists of removing the comments directly from the system catalogues like so (disclaimer - the following code is copied directly from his answer):

```
DELETE FROM pg_description WHERE description = 'something special';
```

Or you could delete the comments based on any other criteria you may choose.

Comment: @Darth Kangooroo, in addition, you should also check out PhilHibbs answer in the same thread. He uses the information_schema to generate `COMMENT` statements.